# What effect will restarting a SharePoint farm Web Front End (WFE) server have on a separate FAST Search index?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, fast-search

What effect on a FAST Search server index would restarting a web front end (WFE) where the WFE and FAST Search servers are independent hosts?

Trying to find minimal impact (FAST Search re-indexing must not be re-initialized!) where we need to restart a WFE but not sure whether it'll have an impact on the FAST Search crawled data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any impact on the search service while you reboot the web front end.

For safe side, make sure all content sources are in idle position while you rebooting, if any crawl is running then let it complete then do the reboot.

Rebooting web front t end will hurt end user ability to access the sites so plan it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for this - and for you very speedy response! We do currently have a problem with our FAST Search crawls taking an almost indefinite time to finish. We have had this prior to me starting in this role and our solution is to restart the FAST Search servers - but this will cause a rebuild of the index - this is not what we want at the moment. The reason I'm treading so carefully is that we'd like to restart the WFE servers because of a disk space issue that seems to be affecting Web Parts. Our biggest concern is will restarting the WFE cause any affect to the FAST Search. It seems not :)

Comment: It should not, as I said make sure no crawl is running and also try to reboot one server at time to minimize the impact.